# Fastest way to split each 2-character string element of a numpy array into 1-character string elements?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array in the format:

`array(['01', '23', '45', '67', '01' ... '67'], dtype='<U2')`

and I would like to know the most efficient way to convert this to a numpy array of the form:

`array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '0', '1' ... '6', ''7])`

(I'm hoping for an answer that does not take into account that this array is a sequence. I'd like an answer that is generally applicable to an array of this form)

I could do this by using a for loop of course, but it seems that would be incredibly slow, as this array is enormous.

Comment: does .view('U1') work?

Comment: Woh, it does. Thank you!